# Perl CGI page visit counter does not increment

Tags: perl, cgi

I was trying out an elementary Perl/CGI script to keep track of visitors coming to a web page. The Perl code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#KEEPING COUNT OF VISITORS IN A FILE
use CGI':standard';
print "content-type:text/html\n\n";
#opening file in read mode
open (FILE,"<count.dat");
$cnt= <FILE>;
close(FILE);
$cnt=$cnt+1;
#opening file to write
open(FILE,">count.dat");
print FILE $cnt;
close(FILE);
print "Visitor count: $cnt";
```

The problem is that the web page does not increment the count of visitors on each refresh. The count remains at the initital value of `$cnt` , ie `1``. Any ideas where the problem lies?

Comment: Why include `CGI` if you never use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never test if the attempt to open the file handle works. Given a file which I had permission to read from and write to that contained a single number and nothing else, the code behaved as intended. If the file did not exist then the count would always be `1`, if it was read-only then it would remain at whatever the file started at.

More general advice:

- `use strict;` and `use warnings;` (and correct code based on their complaints)
- Use the three argument call to `open` as per [the first example in the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- When you `open` a file always `|| handle_the_error_in($!);`
- Don't use a file to store data like this, you have potential race conditions.
- Get [the name of the language](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f) correct

Comment: Well thanks mate :). I'm not much of a Perl programmer and this is my first Perl CGI script :D. Btw, where is the count.dat file located? I could not find it in cgi-bin. I work with Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @amal antony — The script expects it in the same place as the script (although `cgi-bin` is a very bad place to keep this sort of data)

Comment: I got it fixed. It was a problem with the file permissions. Thanks again!

Comment: @Quentin the script expects it in the *current working directory*, which may, or may not (!), be the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate solution that uses only one open() and creates the file if it doesn't already exist.  Locking eliminates a potential race condition among multiple up-daters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);
my $file = 'mycount';
sysopen(my $fh, $file, O_RDWR|O_CREAT) or die "Can't open '$file' $!\n";
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Can't lock $file: $!\n";
my $cnt = <$fh>;
$cnt=0 unless $cnt;
$cnt++;
seek $fh, 0, 0;
print ${fh} $cnt;
close $fh or die "Can't close $file: $\n";
print "Visitor count: $cnt\n";
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem or race conditions. More than one process could write and read at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A few potential reasons:

- 'count.dat' is not being `open`ed for reading. Always test with `or die $!;` at minimum to check if the file opened or not
- The code is not being executed and you think it is

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing that you would have forgotten is to change permissions of the file `count.dat`
Do this :

```
sudo chmod 777 count.dat
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score -2):

You will need to close the webpage and reopen it again. Just refreshing the page won't increment the count.